# Short if-else django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to know if is there any way to do a short if-else in the django template such as in php?

```
  <?=$variable ? 'String for true' : 'String for false'?>
```

If variable value is true, display `String for true` otherwise `String for false`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is [yesno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#yesno) template filter which maps values for true, false.

```
{{ variable|yesno:'String for true,String for false' }}
```

Comment: There is also [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#default)